# Can not deserialize instance, out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson

I need to send a post request to a webservice, but it returns following exception

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL domain.com
```

The actual server response is as following :

```
<html>
<head><title>500 Servlet Exception</title></head>
<body>
<h1>500 Servlet Exception</h1>
<code><pre>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function show() { document.getElementById('trace').style.display = ''; }
</script>
<a style="text-decoration" href="javascript:show();">[show]</a> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance
of com.domain.service.beans.spec.SearchSpec out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: com.caucho.server.connection.ServletInputStreamImpl@7aafd4d3; line: 1, column: 1]
<span id="trace" style="display:none">
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance
of com.domain.service.beans.spec.SearchSpec out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: com.caucho.server.connection.ServletInputStreamImpl@7aafd4d3; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.readWithMessageConverters(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:643)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestBody(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:607)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:427)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:415)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:788)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:717)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:153)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:91)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:103)
    at com.domain.service.filter.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:91)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:187)
    at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:265)
    at com.caucho.server.hmux.HmuxRequest.handleRequest(HmuxRequest.java:436)
    at com.caucho.server.port.TcpConnection.run(TcpConnection.java:682)
    at com.caucho.util.ThreadPool$Item.runTasks(ThreadPool.java:743)
    at com.caucho.util.ThreadPool$Item.run(ThreadPool.java:662)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
</span>
</pre></code>
</body></html>
```

I am sending the request based on following

```
Method: POST
This returns a list of products
Dates are optional.
Destination ID and currencyCode are required.
JSON Request Parameters
{

"startDate":"2013-10-25", "endDate":"2013-10-27", "topX":"1-5", "destId":684, "currencyCode":"EUR", "catId":0,
"subCatId":0, "dealsOnly":false, "sortOrder":"PRICE_FROM_A"
}

so r t O r d e r
Valid sort orders:
TOP_SELLERS - The top sellers - default sortOrder 
REVIEW_AVG_RATING_A - Traveler Rating (low->high) Average 
REVIEW_AVG_RATING_D - Traveler Rating (high->low) Average 
PRICE_FROM_A - Price (low->high)
PRICE_FROM_D - Price (high->low)

topX
For returning results in particular positions. e.g. a value of 11-15 will return the results in position 11 to 15 based on the sort (total of 5 products). Useful for pagination.

catId
Category id from the /service/taxonomy/categories

subCatId
Sub Category id from the /service/taxonomy/categories

dealsOnly
Applicable only when there is no startDate/endDate as it is a destionation search only feature. This API is used for obtaining lists of products for destination pages.
```

**My Code**

```
 public void Search() {


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("startDate", "2014-08-25");
        obj.put("endDate", "2014-08-25");
        obj.put("topX", "1-5");
        obj.put("destId", 684);
        obj.put("currencyCode", "EUR");
        obj.put("catId", 21);
        obj.put("subCatId", 78);
        obj.put("dealsOnly", false);
        obj.put("sortOrder","PRICE_FROM_A");

        JSONArray jsarray = new JSONArray();
        jsarray.add(obj);
        putDataToServer(jsarray.toJSONString());

    }

    public void putDataToServer(String returnedJObject) {

try{
        java.lang.String contentToPost = returnedJObject;

        java.net.URLConnection connection = new java.net.URL("domain.com").openConnection();

        connection.setUseCaches(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + contentToPost.length());

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        java.io.OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(contentToPost.getBytes());
        stream.close();
        System.err.println("request is sent");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        System.err.println(br.readLine());
        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating your json like that? Why not have model and then you can use the Jackson ObjectMapper to create your request data? Either way, it seems the the server is unhappy because you are sending an array

Comment: How to use ObjectMapper? I know how to parse XML response into object but got no idea about JSON, would you help.

Answer (score 0):

The server error indicated that it does not expect an array of objects. Delete this code

```
JSONArray jsarray = new JSONArray();
jsarray.add(obj);
```